# Wi-Fi and Bluetooth constantly disconnecting

Tags: networking, wireless, bluetooth, 20.04, iwlwifi

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and the bluetooth and wifi of my notebook are frequently disconnecting, OUT OF THE BLUE.
They just start **turning on and off every minute**, and I can only solve it by restarting, or waiting it stops *alone*.
Before upgrading to version 20.04,  same thing happened.
I am afraid it is a problem with the notebook's network card.

What do you think it can be? Are there any solutions if it is a software problem?

THANKS GUYS!

```
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1028:020c]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0cf3:0036 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: hey, edited. what do you think?

Comment: This doesn't look like a software problem. That must be a bad contact of the module. Open the case take out the module and clean the conacts. Also tighten the screws.